# How to pronounce the names of supersymmetric partner particles of fermions

Tags: pronunciation, science

The names of supersymmetric partner particles of fermions are formed by s- + the name of the normal particle. E.g.:

- sparticle

  - sfermion

    - squark

      - sup
      - sdown
      - scharm
      - sstrange
      - stop
      - sbottom
    - slepton

      - selectron
      - selectron sneutrino
      - smuon
      - smuon neutrino
      - stau
      - stau sneutrino

(The names of superpartners of bosons are formed differently, by changing -on to -ino, e.g., gluino.)

I couldn't find any information online on how to pronounce these words. Would you pronounce "sfermion" (for instance) as /ˈɛs ˈfɝːmiɑn/ or /ˈsfɝːmiɑn/ or something else?

Comment: Nothing that begins with an S in English is pronounced with ɛs. Do you speak a Latin-based language?? Because Spanish and Portuguese speakers typically change an initial s to that phoneme....so for example, smith becomes esmith [sorry too lazy to do the phonemes].

Comment: @Lambie: I think the idea is that it might be pronounced as the letter "s," like how "X-ray" starts with /ɛks/. That kind of pronunciation becomes tempting when faced with things like "sstrange" or "sbottom."

Comment: "Sparticle" is apparently short for "super-particle," so I guess a third theoretical pronunciation for "sfermion" would be /ˈsuːpɚˌfɝmiɑn/ (US) or /ˈs(j)uːpəˌfɜːmɪɒn/  (British). I haven't found pronunciations with /ɔn/ listed for "fermion" in any dictionary.

Comment: Well, I dunno. that symbol is for the s in English. So, I don't see a difference then between the two ones posted by the OP.

Comment: okay to be honest I'm not very good at finding the IPA for words

Comment: @sumelic: The standard pronunciation in the U.S. is /-ɑn/. *Electrawn* and *fermiyawn* just sound wrong to me. The author of book you found currently lives in Australia ... maybe they pronounce them differently there, or maybe he's just confused about how non-Australians pronunce them.

Comment: @sumelic: looking through the book you linked to, it appears that the author merges the British vowels /ɒ/ and /ɔ/. The only place I know where this happens is in the traditional Boston dialect (*party* = /pɑti/ and *potty* = /pɔti/). But maybe some Australians do this, too.

Comment: @PeterShor: Interesting! Actually, the author seems to distinguish them by vowel length:  /ɒ/ is transcribed as /ɔ/, and /ɔː/ is transcribed as /ɔː/. He says the scheme is based on that used in [Daniel Jones](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-english.htm)' *English Pronouncing Dictionary.* So I was wrong; the actual transcription here is in fact unambiguously the "lot" vowel, as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have heard these pronounced, one says "Es" and then the following particle name, Es Fermion.

On a side note, the "on" receives the same pronunciation as the "on" in "proton."

Comment: Would you know why "a sneutrino" has far more results on Google than "an sneutrino"?

Comment: @user165604 I think that is because sneutrino can be pronounced whereas sbottom or sdown cannot.  I remember hearing professors talk about the hyperbolic functions...for tanh I heard "tanch" or "hyperbolic tangent."  Sinh was pronounced sinch.